# Is it ok, if i put my leg up on the bench while bench press

Tags: bench-press

[image]

If this position is wrong?
and when bringing the weight down, Do i need to rest bar on my chest slightly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This position is as much wrong as it is correct.

If your goal is pure hypertrophy or you want to focus more on just the pecs and shoulders this type of 'style' is better also it does not have much impact on your spine. Please take care to keep the elbows closer to your body then the guy on the Image as it is healthier for your shoulders.

If your goal is strength, you should consider a different 'style' and treat the bench press as a whole body movement. Therefore you have to use your legs and a tight back. There are a lot of different youtube Videos out there and you should find the correct form for you.

> The truth is actually quite simple – both ways can be valuable in your training, depending on your goal...
>   http://angrytrainerfitness.com/2012/01/fitness-fact-or-fiction-bench-press-feet-up-or-down/

In general there is no prescription on what the correct form is, try to find it out for your goal and body and work on it.

The important part is to always think of shoulder and back development too, as people nowadays neglect the body Parts that are not visible in the mirror, but are important for muscular balance and health.

Comment: No. This position is wrong. Your unstable and it causes injuries, also you can lift less.

Comment: @Lasse - What injuries are caused by this? Lifting less ... for what - Powerlifting? it depends on your goals and there is no right or wrong ... if your goal is max weight use powerlifting style benching if your goal is hypertrophy this one is perfectly fine and you can work up easily to 140 - 150 kgs in this position - what would be totally fine for muscle grow... right? You can cause more injuries by lifting heavy weights and legs low  or making a bad back... in this pos your back is flat and you are targeting the pecs and triceps more.

Answer (score 2):

While you will see a lot of people doing this it is incorrect form, especially if you are lifting heavy weight,  your feet should be planted firmly on the floor and will help you maintain your balance.

Answer (score 2):

1. This form is wrong because your stability is bad. It's very important to keep a stable & core-involved position during your bench press, which means contracting your abs and keeping your feet on the ground, pushing through your heels. Personally, I can affirm that my bench quickly improved by about 10 pounds since I started following this approach.
2. It depends on your goal. If you're training goal is developing pure strength, it may help, but then your should consider doing dead press ([here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jk4Lu4VOmXA) a video example). If your main goal is hypertrophy, there are better approaches.

Comment: This position might be wrong, BUT if you place your feet on the ground you might go to swayback (? hope this is correct english). And this behaviour is absolutely wrong!

Comment: This style of benching is not wrong, I would even say it is even healthier then the feet on the ground style as it for ces you to use less weight and is safer for the spine and abs. It depends on the goals or circumstances one might have that dictates the right style

Comment: If you focus on shoulders/abs, there are plenty of better exercises for that. Putting legs this way means loading less weight, less than one is available to bench, and thus delaying the progress. In what circumstances would you prefer this position? My only thought is shoulders injury but then I'd avoid barbell bench completely.

Comment: You can use this bench position for speed benching, only for hypertrophy work where you not focus on lifting max weight, or if you are prone to hernia or other form of injuries abs/shoulders but dont want to substitute the exercise. ..

Comment: Btw ever tried floor presses? They are helpfull in strength development. .. you are flat on the ground and your legs at same hight !!

Comment: @Ger_Moki, There is nothing wrong with slight arch in your back in a bench press.

Comment: @Lasse, there is nothing wrong with a flat back neither.